# Wamp Apache does not restart after changing documentroot

Tags: apache, windows-7, wamp

I want to change the documentroot as follows

```
#DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
DocumentRoot "d:/home/development/web/"
<Directory   "d:/home/development/web/">
```

The commented out Documentroot is the original one. When I change it the way shown above, after restarting all services the wamp icon goes from green to red and then to orange, never to become green again. Exiting and restarting does not help either. Localhost is not found, so I presume Apache is not (sufficiently) started. The directory does exist, capitalization is correct. The Apache errorlog file seems ok. Changing the DocumentRoot point to its orginal location makes everything work again. What am I doing wrong??

Using 64 bit wamp, apache 2.4.2.

**Update**

I found out that the documentroot placed on a mapped network drive which in my case is drive D:. Having the documentroot point to a directory on a harddisk all is well. Anybody any idea how to let documentroot to a mapped drive?

Comment: I've never had any luck with this. There are a ton of people trying though, if you do a quick search you may find something that works for you. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3949190.htm

Comment: For potential furture visitors: The same error message is raised when one forgets to update or makes a typo in the line with directory permissions, which points by default to the old DocumentRoot (in pure Apache, this line is sth like `<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">`).

Comment: @Sarah, the link is very useful and contains recommendations for situations like mine. They didn't work for me alas but thanks (and +1 anyway.